# Move data between elastic search clusters

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, opensearch, elasticsearch-indices

I am new to elasticsearch. I'm trying to create a snapshot for migration from ELK deployed on my Kubernetes cluster to opensearch service, but I don't want to snapshot the whole cluster only some indices, any pointers please on how to export data to storage service and import it in my destination clusters?

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot supports the specified index as below

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_repository/snapshot_2?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "index_1,index_2",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false,
  "metadata": {
    "taken_by": "user123",
    "taken_because": "backup before upgrading"
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/create-snapshot-api.html#create-snapshot-api-example